# Update model and HTML after user action

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular controller:

```
application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService) {

  $scope.model = {
    images: []
  }

  var list = function () {
    ImageService.GetList()
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images)
     })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  }

  $scope.vote = function (image) {
    ImageService.Vote(image)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  };

  list();

});
```

The service returns a list of images as follows:

```
{"Images": [
  {"Key":"22","Url":"http://www.domain.com/i/img22.jpg", "Votes": 120},
  {"Key":"88","Url":"http://www.domain.com/i/img88.jpg", "Votes": 428}
]}
```

I display a list of images each having a vote button and the number of votes.

```
<div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
  <img data-ng-src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
  <a href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)">VOTE</a>
  <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
</div>
```

When a user votes an image I would like to disable the vote button, even if only for this page request, and increase the number of votes by one.

**PLAN**

My idea would be to add a property "HasBeenVoted" as False to each image after being loaded from the service and when the image is voted change it to true and increase its votes by one. And of course sync with the HTML to disable the Vote button and update the {{image.Votes}}

**PROBLEM**

1. How to include the HasBeenVoted in all image here:

   $scope.model.images = $scope.model.images.concat(data.Images)
2. How to update HasBeenVoted and Votes Number in the model and HTML here:

   $scope.vote = function (image) {
       ImageService.Vote(image)
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
     };

Could someone, please, help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to check serverside you could just change your JS/HTML as follows:

HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
  <img data-ng-src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
  <a ng-disabled="image.HasBeenVoted" href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)">VOTE</a>
  <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
 $scope.vote = function (image) {
    image.HasBeenVoted = true;
    image.Votes += 1;
    ImageService.Vote(image)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  };
```

This works because image.HasBeenVoted will be false initially and true for each image you vote on.

But this does not persist if you navigate. I suggest you extend the service to handle this server side. Your server should be responsible for this. Your response should have the property HasBeenVoted for the logged in user.

Edit: you could do the check in your controller instead, change your HTML + JS as follows:

CSS

```
.disabled {
    opacity: .2;
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-repeat='image in model.images'>
  <img data-ng-src="{{image.Url}}" alt="" />
  <a ng-class="{disabled: image.HasBeenVoted}" href="" data-ng-click="vote(image)">VOTE</a>
  <span>{{image.Votes}}</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $scope.vote = function (image) {
    if (image.HasBeenVoted) { return; }

    image.HasBeenVoted = true;
    image.Votes += 1;
    ImageService.Vote(image)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) { })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) { });
  };
```

Comment: With your solution the votes are increased fine but I am still able to vote ... The anchor does not get disabled.

Comment: I think ng-disabled does not work with anchor tags ... Only with buttons and so on ... I probably I will need to do something different

Comment: see updated answer, you could do the check inside your controller and add i.e. a disabled class to your anchor tag that reduces the opacity.

Comment: Yes, that was what I just ended doing. I just marked your answer. Thanks